# How to Select kind of objects in Vue.js

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

i use this code to select all objects in person and i put them in Cash :[]

```
  this.cash= person.userinvoice.concat(person.usercashfloat )
```

In **person.usercashfloat** i have an element named **validate** , sometimes is= 0 and sometimes it's = 1

i want to select only objetcs with validate = 1
How can we do that ? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it simply using the following code block  :

```
  if((person.usercashfloat.validate==1){       
     this.cash= person.userinvoice.concat(person.usercashfloat ) 
   }
```